# Error in Pair Bypass In J2ME And Discover Hidden Bluetooth

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I am going to develop a bluetooth chat using J2ME. But my problem is - How do i bypass the pair (pass key or the authentication process) using J2ME so that the program automatically connect to another device ?

Another Question is - How do i discover a hidden bluetooth device/ phone using J2ME ?

Answer (score 0):

U first create a service and registered as some UUID in src device.Then in another device with the help of the UUID u should pair the device with each other without passcode,password,etc.But here u use the same UUID in both side.